# Multiple clicks prevents AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have page with multiple buttons, which sometimes can be clicked really fast - however it seems like Chrome can hold up with the speed?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.favorite-button').unbind('click').click(function() {
    addLine($(this).data('line-id'));
     });
});
```

addLine() function:

```
function addLine(lineID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'add-line.php',
        data: { lineID : lineID },
        success: function(server_response)  {
            $('#counter-lines').html(server_response);
        }
    });
}
```

What can I do so that Chrome will register and complete every ajax call?
It does not seem to be a limit in Chrome - even two fast clicks will result in a missing ajax call...

Comment: Are you sure that it is not the order of the responses that comes back is the issue? It might be that the first click comes back after the 2nd....

Comment: Dunno? It should not matter though. Every click inserts a row into a database - and if all AJAX request were completed, I should be able to click a button 10 seconds later and have all lines appear... However, all the rows are not inserted into DB as they should be :( (only if I force my finger to chill with the clicks ;))

Comment: Did you check in the chrome network tab that you don't get an error back?

Comment: No errors - but you did bring me on the right track! My lineID is generated in php by md5-hashing current datetime and also this ID is set as primary index in mySQL - so when the clicks occur in the same second the line is not inserted. Problem solved ! :D Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you just don't get the responses by order.

I see that you tell the server what ID to give the line. So why don't you keep the sent lineID in a global variable, and when you get the response you can see if it's a response to the most recent request.

like:

```
var latest_line = null;
    function addLine(lineID) {
            latest_line = lineID;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'add-line.php',
                data: { lineID : lineID },
                success: function(server_response)  {
                    // Is this the most recent request?
                    if (latest_line == lineID)
                    {
                        $('#counter-lines').html(server_response);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a solution to the OP's issue.  Also, you don't need to assign `lineID` to `curr_line`.  The argument `lineID` will work just fine for what you are doing.  Nothing outside this function can change the `lineID` argument.

Comment: Sorry. I thought lineID was a global variable. Just now I saw it's a parameter.

Comment: Once I fixed my first issue (see comments below my question), this issue did come up too! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code need to be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    js_Codes();

    /* The rest of your code that will not reload after ajax request */

});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    /* Here we call the codes that will reload after your ajax request */
    js_Codes();
});

function js_Codes(){

    function clickOpenDialog(){
        $('.btOpenDialog').off('click',clickOpenDialog);
        fn_open_Dialog_Click($(this).prop('alt'), function(){$('.btOpenDialog').on('click',clickOpenDialog);});
        return false;
    };

    function fn_Open_Dialog_Click(myString){
        var myArray = myString.split(';');
        /* whatever u want with your page with a string param array */

    };

    $('.btOpenDialog').on('click',clickOpenDialog);
}
```

works fine for me.. ;)